# Pass multiple variables through segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I've seen lots of tutorials where people pass a single variable through a segue to a separate view-controller. But how do I send maybe a whole struct or class of information over to a separate segue? and unwrap it on the other side? Example: in a table view i click on a player's name, and it will segue to show details in another view controller?

Example: baseball roster lineup...

```
class Player {
    var playerName: String = ""
    var playerPosition: String = ""
    var playerImage: UIImage = ""
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedPlayer = player[indexPath.row].playerName

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "player", sender: selectedPlayer)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `prepare` function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "player" {
        if let player = sender as? Player {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.player = player
        }
    }
}
```

This function will be called when you call `performSegue`. Declare a player variable in your `secondViewController` and you´ll just pass the variable in your `prepare` function.

And in your `didSelectRowAt` change:

```
let selectedPlayer = player[indexPath.row].playerName
```

To:

```
let selectedPlayer = player[indexPath.row]
```

So you pass the entire `Player` object instead of just the `playerName`.

Comment: It would probably help to include the changes needed in the `didSelectRowAt` method posted in the question.